# Order how multiple threads reacquire std::unique_lock<std::mutex> after std::condition_variable::notify_all

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Here is some piece of code that will be called from multiple threads. Predicate for `std::condition_variable::wait` will be a little different for each thread but it doesn't change the problem.

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{connection_mutex};
cv.wait(lock, 
     [conn = shared_from_this()]
     {
         return conn->connection_is_made();
     }
);

//do some stuff
lock.unlock();
```

I read this at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

> When the condition variable is notified, a timeout expires, or a spurious wakeup occurs, the thread is awakened, and the mutex is atomically reacquired. The thread should then check the condition and resume waiting if the wake up was spurious.

From this I understand that `lock` will be locked, than a predicate lambda will be checked, and if it returns `true` the `lock` will remain locked and I can continue to do some stuff under the protection of this mutex. When `std::condition_variable` is notified by `notify_one()` member function it makes perfect sense.

But what happens when `std::condition_variable` is notified by `notify_all()`? I cant find in documentation if all the threads are woken up and than "waits in a line" to lock a mutex and only then check what the predicate returns or maybe they do something else.

---

EDIT : I started to think a little after seeing comments below. `std::condition_variable::wait` expects `std::unique_lock` as its 1st argument and when `std::condition_variable::wait` is woken up after notification - `std::unique_lock` will be reacquired. Now if multiple threads are waiting on the same notification, than when `notify_all()` is finally called on specific `std::condition_variable` **only 1 thread will be able lock the mutex and all the other threads will go back to sleep. So I don't see any point of having `notify_all()` member function at all if it has the same effect as `notify_one()` except less efficient.** I mean if mutex must be reacquired for
a thread to get past `std::condition_variable::wait`, then its no way all the waiting threads can do it simultaneously.

Comment: If you are asking about the notification order, then this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912322/condition-variable-deadlock

Comment: Thanks for the answer but In this case I'm not worried about never receiving notify_all() signal. I just want to know how multiple threads act when they wait on the same condition_variable, then receive the notification by notify_all() and then try to acquire the same mutex.

Comment: It's up to the OS scheduler. You can't know which thread gets the mutex first.

Comment: they are kind of waiting in the line? 1 thread gets it, do its stuff and when mutex is relaised another thread instantly reacquires the mutex and checks its predicate and so on untill all the threads that were waiting reacquired the mutex?

Comment: Of all the threads that are awoken, some may find the mutex already locked and thus they will block (= go to sleep) on the mutex.

Comment: According to cppreference, all threads are woken up. But if they are just going to "line up" for a mutex, then all but one will go back to sleep anyhow. So in that scenario, why call notify all instead of notify one? Notify all is nice if all waiting threads can make progress at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, all of you! I think the Nir Friedman's answer is the most informative so I could accept it as the right answer if you would rewrite it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests to see if all the threads were waking up after the call to notify_all(), even the ones that were not scheduled to be woken up as 1st ones.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex M;
std::condition_variable CV;
int var = 0;


int main()
{
    std::thread t1{
        []{
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{M};
            while(var != 1){
                CV.wait(lck);
                std::cout << "t1 woken up and (i != 1) = " 
                          << (var != 1) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    };

    std::thread t2{
        []{
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{M};
            while(var != 2){
                CV.wait(lck);
                std::cout << "t2 woken up and (i != 2) = " 
                          << (var != 2) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    };

    std::thread t3{
        []{
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{M};
            while(var != 3){
                CV.wait(lck);
                std::cout << "t3 woken up and (i != 3) = " 
                          << (var != 3) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    };

    std::thread t4{
        []{
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{M};
            while(var != 4){
                CV.wait(lck);
                std::cout << "t4 woken up and (i != 4) = " 
                          << (var != 4) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{M};
        var = i;
        CV.notify_all();
        lck.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{1});
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

And here are the results

```
t3 woken up and (i != 3) = 1 //spurious wakeup


t3 woken up and (i != 3) = 1
t4 woken up and (i != 4) = 1
t2 woken up and (i != 2) = 1
t1 woken up and (i != 1) = 0


t3 woken up and (i != 3) = 1
t4 woken up and (i != 4) = 1
t2 woken up and (i != 2) = 0


t3 woken up and (i != 3) = 0
t4 woken up and (i != 4) = 1


t4 woken up and (i != 4) = 0
```

So I'm happy to see that no matter what thread is woken up 1st, all the notified threads are woken up in some random order with a single call to `notify_all()`. Looks like when one of the woken up threads by `notify_all()` (say thread A) are unlocking the `mutex` after doing some job, the next thread that was woken up by the same call to `notify_all()` as thread A is automatically locking the same `mutex` that thread A just unlocked. This continues until all the threads that were woken up by `notify_all()` have locked/unlocked the same `mutex` that was used to protect the shared data.